# Merge many commit into a single one under same branch

Tags: github, git-rebase, git-commit

Using git, I created a local branch to work in. Then I committed my work progressively. So, I get 3 commit in the same pull request I'd liked to merge them into a single one.

I founded that there is a way to do it if we follow these steps:

- `git rebase -i HEAD~3`

=> All commit in the branch are listed as below

```
pick mycommit1
pick mycommit2
pick mycommit3
```

- To meld them into the first one, I have to set the commands of mycommit2 and mycommit3 to `squash` instead of `pick`

But, in my case, there is lot of commits between my commits in the master branch, thus, I can not do this.

By consequent, I would ask if I can do the merge **JUST** in my pull request.

Your ideas are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fixup` command while rebasing. This command does the same thing as `squash` but while keep the message of the first commit. For instance:

```
pick 123abcd
pick abc1234
pick a1b2c34
```

You can change this to:

```
pick 123abcd
f abc1234
f a1b2c34
```

Now you join these 3 commits into one commit which will get the first message. If you want to edit the message once, you can do it like this:

```
pick 123abcd
f abc1234
s a1b2c34
```

This means that these 3 commits will be joined into one commit and you can edit that commit.

---

Extra Tip: To make it easier to change every `pick` to a command, you can simply use Vims block select feature to select all 'pick's and change it to the command you want.